# Calculating the Risk Free Rate

Tags: risk, risk-free, ratio

I have an assignment and I have to calculate the risk-free rate with the following data:

Stock A: E(R) = 10%  ;  Standard Deviation = 5%.

Stock B: E(R) = 20%  ;  Standard Deviation = 10%.

I also know that the correlation coefficient of the two assets is -1.

I have tried to use the Sharpe Ratio or the CAPM formula for risk-free rate, but without any success.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**  If these 2 stocks have perfect negative correlation (correlation: -1), then you can construct a risk free portfolio.  What would the return on that risk free portfolio be?